# Disable Ctrl and Alt key in Win App C#

Tags: c#, registry

I have a app that disable <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>DEL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>, Start Menu of windows registry.

Can I disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys, that user don't use any shortcut keys of windows?

For example : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> , <kbd>Alt</kbd>

Comment: Do you want those keys to be disabled inside your application or globally?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this from the application. Those keys do not reach the application until the operating system processed it and the functions you want to disable are operating system functions.

What you are probably looking for is called `Kiosk mode`, a mode where the user cannot chose the program that is running and has no access to the operating system.

Comment: I have a app that run in windows startup, and lock the taskbar and start menu, i want lock control keys, for example when user open ie dont use Ctrl+n for open new ie.

Comment: That seems like a very hacky solution to a problem already fixed with kiosk mode. You are trying to build a feature that a multi-million dollar corporation already built. Don't waste time and resources rebuilding something that already exists.